# Non-numeric matrix

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a problem with my matrix. 
The first row and the first column are not numeric. I therfore get "x must be numeric everytime I try to do something with the matrix in R.

Picture of the matrix:
[Count matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwlHb.png)

The matrix has 43 columns and 1,000,000 lines.

Can anyone help me define the matrix? I don't want to loose the information I have in the non-numeric lines/columns.

I have seen other examples on this page of how to do it, but it has been small matrices where they have defined it manually and since my matrix is that large it's not a possibility for me

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stack overflow!  While you ask a pertinent question, how you ask can it can help us provide you with an answer. Please see  [ask] to help you with asking a question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd like to add the helps to get good and fast support when providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey, thanks. I have tried to specify :)

Comment: Instead of an image, provide a small sample data set that people can use to reproduce your code and find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use row names and column names to house the non-numeric data, while casting the rest of the matrix to numeric type. Like this for example:

Create a dummy matrix to demonstrate:

```
m0 = matrix(sample(0:9, 36,T), ncol = 6)
m0[, 1] = c("",letters[1:5])
m0[1, ] = c("",letters[1:5])

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,] ""   "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e" 
#[2,] "a"  "5"  "6"  "2"  "0"  "7" 
#[3,] "b"  "9"  "0"  "5"  "6"  "3" 
#[4,] "c"  "9"  "7"  "6"  "6"  "0" 
#[5,] "d"  "5"  "5"  "7"  "8"  "3" 
#[6,] "e"  "4"  "0"  "9"  "4"  "4"
```

Now make a new matrix with the numeric values in its body, and the row/column names used to house the character strings

```
m1 = (m0[-1,-1])        # extract just the numeric part of the matrix into a new matrix
mode(m1) = "numeric"    # cast this into numeric rather than character type
colnames(m1) = m0[1,-1] # use the first row of original as column names
rownames(m1) = m0[-1,1] # same for row names

#   a b c d e
# a 5 6 2 0 7
# b 9 0 5 6 3
# c 9 7 6 6 0
# d 5 5 7 8 3
# e 4 0 9 4 4
```